# It is possible to ban an android version for an app?

Tags: android, android-version

I have a problem with some android versions (10, 11, 12) with my application. The problem is due to an edit box layout that i don't like for this 3 versions.

Here is my manifest :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Normally, the application try to use the 19th version and if the smartphone version is lower, the application is going to use the maximum one that it can.

So i am wondering if it is possible to do something like that :

```
Your smartphone version     Version use for aplication
7                           7
8                           8
9                           9
10                          9
11                          9
12                          9
13                          13
14                          14
15                          15
16                          16
17                          17
18                          18
19                          19
```

Thanks a lot,

Comment: ... does it have anything to do with rounded corners, maybe? Because there's a well known bug in API Level 12. And a well known workaround, too.

Comment: No, I don't know why but in my app for this version the edit box by default wirting in white on white (that not really cool if you want to see what you have wirting :p)

Comment: What about try to fix the bug?

Comment: Maybe you can simply change the theme?

Comment: I probably can do it but it looks long because for API level<10 it wirte black on white and for API level > 13 it is white on black. So i will need to correct all my editText in my code. So I was wondering if there is a faster solution by banning the app version

Comment: Change the theme looks a good idea, I didn't know about it. I will have a look.

Comment: Excluding users from using your app is never a good idea. Don't be lazy and try to do a workaround. Are you sure this bug is not caused by you? Maybe there api need some special things to work. Search. Or maybe change the theme according to the API version.

Comment: This not excluding user because people with API lvl 10 can use the API lvl 9. It is working well if i do android:targetSdkVersion="9" but i will have a look at theme as you and Golem said

Comment: did you try changing the edit text layout ? the edit text is fully stylable...